# renderText isn't printing output in my Shiny application

Tags: r, plot, shiny, cat

I have a simple Shiny application that can print the normal distribution for a dataset.  It uses selectInput to allow the user to change which dataset they want to see plotted.  That part of the app works.  I wanted to add a renderText section under the renderPlot to display the mean and standard deviation depending on what the user chooses, but no text is being displayed on the application.  Instead, my text is outputted to the console when I would instead like it be displayed underneath the plot in the actual Shiny app.

As of now, here is my code for server.R:

```
# This application will allow the user to view the standard normal distribution for multiple different datasets
# This app demonstrates use of the selectInput and submitButton features available in Shiny

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)


# Cars dataset
data("mtcars")

x_cars <- mtcars$mpg
avg_cars <- mean(x_cars)
stdev_cars <- sd(x_cars)
y_cars <- dnorm(x_cars, avg_cars, stdev_cars)


# PlantGrowth dataset
data("PlantGrowth")

x_plants <- filter(PlantGrowth, group =="ctrl")
x_plants <- select(x_plants, weight)
x_plants <- as.numeric(unlist(x_plants))

avg_plants <- mean(x_plants)
stdev_plants <- sd(x_plants)
y_plants <- dnorm(x_plants, avg_plants, stdev_plants)


# USArrests
data("USArrests")

x_murders <- select(USArrests, Murder)
x_murders <- as.numeric(unlist(x_murders))

avg_murders <- mean(x_murders)
stdev_murders <- sd(x_murders)
y_murders <- dnorm(x_murders, avg_murders, stdev_murders)







# If statements for determining which dataset is the desired output
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

        if (input$Dataset == "mtcars") {
          plot(x_cars,y_cars,main="Average mpg of all cars in mtcars dataset", xlab="mpg", ylab="Probability Density")
        }
        if (input$Dataset == "PlantGrowth") {
          plot(x_plants,y_plants,main="Average weight of plants in the control group", xlab="Plant Weight",ylab="Probability Density")
        }
        if (input$Dataset == "USArrests") {
          plot(x_murders,y_murders,main="Number of murders by US state", xlab="Murder Count", ylab="Probability Density")
        }


    })
    
    output$textOut <- renderText({
      
        cat("This simple Shiny app demonstrates usage of the selectInput and submitButton features\n")
        if (input$Dataset == "mtcars") {
          cat("Mean: ", avg_cars, "\n")
          cat("Standard Deviation: ", stdev_cars, "\n")
        }
        if (input$Dataset == "PlantGrowth") {
          cat("Mean: ", avg_plants, "\n")
          cat("Standard Deviation: ", stdev_plants, "\n")
        }
        if (input$Dataset == "USArrests") {
          cat("Mean: ", avg_murders, "\n")
          cat("Standard Deviation: ", stdev_murders, "\n")
        }
      
    })

})
```

And here is my code for ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(inputId="Dataset","Dataset",label="Select desired dataset:",choices=c("mtcars","PlantGrowth","USArrests")),
            
            submitButton("Confirm Changes")),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("distPlot"),
            textOutput("textOut")
        )
    )
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `cat()`. You have to return a string in `renderText`. So replace `cat` with `paste`.

Comment: I have already tried that.  When I use paste, only the final paste statement  ever gets printed.

Comment: Can renderText handle more than one strings returned at a time?

Comment: @burble_gurp007 Ah yes sorry. You have to join the strings: `paste(string1, string2, sep = "\n")`.